# How to add external folder into docker and then set environment variable

Tags: java, dockerfile

My Java code expects GATE_HOME to be set on the system. It works perfectly fine in my desktop. While add that to docker, I have the following code:

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.4
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ADD test.jar test.jar
ADD GATE /usr/local/GATE
ENV GATE_HOME /usr/local/GATE
```

I am trying to copy the GATE folder to the docker image and set GATE_HOME. Is this the correct approach. If I do this, then will my Java code understand System.getProperty("GATE_HOME")?

As of now, I am getting null for getProperty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look to **[Docker "Manage data in containers" documentation (link)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)** :

> ### Manage data in containers
>
> In this section you’re going to learn how you can manage data inside
>   and between your Docker containers.
>
> You’re going to look at the two primary ways you can manage data with
>   Docker Engine.
>
> - Data volumes
> - Data volume containers

Example :

> ### Add a data volume
>
> You can add a data volume to a container using the `-v` flag with the
>   `docker create` and `docker run` command. You can use the `-v`
>   multiple times to mount multiple data volumes. Now, mount a single
>   volume in your web application container.
>
> ```
> $ docker run -d -P --name web -v /webapp training/webapp python app.py
> ```

**[Volume with Dockerfile (link)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume)**

> ```
> FROM ubuntu
> RUN mkdir /myvol
> RUN echo "hello world" > /myvol/greeting
> VOLUME /myvol
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am not able to figure out how I can use this to set an ENV or System property with this.